# Incrementing int value using the getter setter

Tags: java

I have a requirement to increment int value. So I have made getter/setter for it and I applied this logic for the increment value of int:

```
public class MyOrderDetails {

    private int count = 0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void increment(int increment) {
        setCount(getCount() + 1);
    }

 }
```

Is this right way what I am doing or is this pro grammatically wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a. If you just want to increment, you don't need to provide any setter.

b. In

```
public void increment() {
    setCount(getCount() + 1);
}
```

You can directly access the count variable, so `count++` is enough, doesn't need to setCount.

c. Usually need a reset method.

d. count++ is not atomic, so synchronize if it is used in multi-threading scenario.

```
public synchronized void increment() {
    count++;
}
```

So finally the class would be:

```
class Counter{
    private int count = 0;

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    public synchronized void increment(){
        count++;
    }

    public void reset(){
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

So you can use the class like:

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
counter.increment() //increment the counter
int count = counter.getCount();
```

Comment: i get the what i requirement but sir my question is Is this is wright way to do some logically method in pojo class..

Comment: Yes, my answer is about something that I think you did it wrong. @SulabhGajjar

Comment: Thanxs a lot sir for keep this method as a synchronized. I dnt know the meaning of the synchronized but at now I got meaning of it.. again thanxs a lot sir...

Comment: With pleasure :). @SulabhGajjar

Comment: I have put your method in my pojo class. but is it wright way to apply logic in pojo class.??

Comment: So sir how can I increment the value at that time when I get the method..?

Comment: It is my requirement thanxs a lot sir for help.. @Jermaine Xu

Answer (score 5):

Why do you not just do?

```
public void increment() {
    count++;
}
```

And what is the int parameter to the increment() function for?